# How to get the correct webapi description for customized route

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created a customized HttpControllerSelector class to support area in asp.net webapi, e.g. the route template "api/{area}/{controller}/{action}/id" can be reflected to the controller class named xxx.Controllers.Area.DummyController. Then I use below statement to get api description,

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions
```

but I found the RelativePath property in ApiDescription is not correct, it will miss the area, e.g. the url: api/dummyarea/dummycontroller/list corresponding RelativePath will be api/dummycontroller/list.

Do you know how to get the correct RelativePath?